# Fetch table head value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to fetch the table head value using javascript as I need to do some changes on that text.

Below is sample html code and my javascript code.

```
    <div class="abbResponsiveTableContainer">
        <table class="abbResponsiveTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>AAA</th>
                    <th>BBB</th>
                    <th>CCC</th>
                    <th>DDD</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="odd">
                    <td>
                        90 / 100 % </td>
                    <td>
                        4839 W </td>
                    <td>
                        1.9 % </td>
                    <td>
                        97.6 % </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    
    <script>

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() 
        { 

        gettablehead();
        });

        function gettablehead()
         {
            var headvalue = document.querySelectorAll(".abbResponsiveTable > thead > tr > th")
            
            for (var i=0; i < headvalue.length; i++) 
            {       
                alert(headvalue[i].value);  
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I need to fetch all the table head values like `AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD` but I'm getting `undefined` in the headvalue variable and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: only input type elements (input, textarea ..) have a `.value` ,,, use `.textContent`

Comment: thank you for your quick answer its working now kindly add it as a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a loop where you iterate through HTMLCollection of the header elements of your table.

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tableHeader");

for (let element of elements) {
  console.log(element.textContent);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="abbResponsiveTableContainer">
    <table class="abbResponsiveTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="tableHeader">AAA</th>
          <th class="tableHeader">BBB</th>
          <th class="tableHeader">CCC</th>
          <th class="tableHeader">DDD</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr class="odd">

          <td>
            90 / 100 % </td>
          <td>
            4839 W </td>
          <td>
            1.9 % </td>
          <td>
            97.6 % </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```